# How to rename multiple files in powershell from parent folder?

Tags: powershell

Hello I would like to know is there a way to replace multiple filenames from parent folder?

I was able to rename multiple files using command below, but I have to access each folder first to rename multiple files.

```
dir .\* -include ('*.mp4','*.srt') | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\[','' -replace '\]','' }
```

I was trying to replace `dir .\*` to `dir .\**\*` to select from parent folder but didn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want is the `-Recurse` switch:

```
dir "the folder" -Recurse -Include ('*.mp4','*.srt')
```

Note that this will recurse **all** levels of subdirectories.

Comment: just found out I can use `dir .` from the parent then add  `-Recurse -Include ('*.mp4')` for specific file type

Comment: @flyingduck92 Did you find out because @marsze answered the question?  If so you should credit him as such by accepting the answer. @Theo's answer also mentioned the `-Literal` parameter which also seems germane to your work. And, dare I say that I also gave pertinent info.  Please accept and/or upvote as you see fit, but I don't think you should post essentially the same thing as a separate answer.

Comment: @Steven I voted everyone and accepted answer from marsze already

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by adding the `-Recurse` switch to `Get-ChildItem` (dir is alias to Get-ChildItem).
When searching for files that contain square brackets, you need to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter.

Also, be aware that there is a snag if you pipe the results from that directly to `Rename-Item`..
When doing so, `Get-ChildItem` may pick up the already processed files again, wasting time of course, so to prevent that you can either do:

```
$rootFolder = 'X:\WhereTheFilesAre'
(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $rootFolder -Include '*.mp4','*.srt' -File -Recurse) | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\[|]' }
```

or

```
$rootFolder = 'X:\WhereTheFilesAre'
$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $rootFolder -Include '*.mp4','*.srt' -File -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) { 
    $file | Rename-Item -NewName { $file.Name -replace '\[|]' } 
}
```

Comment: Awesome you don't need the 2nd escape "\" in the RegEx.  Simple but I didn't know...

Comment: How come you don't need to escape the `]` on the regex, didn't know that!

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Well... you just don't need to escape it. Try `[regex]::Escape('[]')`, you will find only the opening square bracket will be escaped: ``\[]``. You **DO** need to escape both if you are using a character list like ``-replace '[\[\]]'``

Answer (score 4):

In additional to [marsze's concise answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68784313/4749264) and realizing this isn't really a performance question:

`-Include` is much slower than `-Filter` because it filters after retrieving from the file system. Whereas, `-Filter` has the file system do the heavy lifting. In essence `-Filter` is a nuanced version of moving filtering operations left in the command/pipeline to improve performance.  However, `-Filter` doesn't take multiple values!  That said, you may still be able to exploit this characteristic using a loop, something like:

```
'*.mp4','*.srt' |
ForEach-Object{
    Get-ChildItem .\ -Filter $_ -File
} | 
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\[|\]' }
```

`-File` works even though you are using `-Recurse` and may carry a modest performance improvement. I also shortened the `-replace` to 1 operation which can only help further.

Comment: Not to be chatty, but humorous banter makes my day, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

I just found out I could use `dir .` to select all files (with specific file types), including files in subdirectories.

```
dir . -Recurse -Include ('*.srt', '*.mp4') | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\[|\]','' }
```